# System of ODE's - Why does this vector function connect two constant vectors continuously?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Given the system of two ODE's 
$\frac{{d{\mathbf{w}}}}{{d\xi }} = {\mathbf{r}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))$, 
with
$\lambda ({\mathbf{w}}(\xi )) = \xi $
and 
${\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L})) = {{\mathbf{u}}_L}$,
${\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R})) = {{\mathbf{u}}_R}$

where $\xi=x/t$,

$x,\;t \in \mathbb{R}$

${{\mathbf{u}}_L},{{\mathbf{u}}_R} \in {\mathbb{R}^2}$,

${\mathbf{u}}:{\mathbb{R}^2} \to \mathbb{R}^2$,

${\mathbf{u}}(x,t) = {\mathbf{w}}(x/t) = {\mathbf{w}}(\xi )$

why does that imply that the function ${\mathbf{w(\xi)}}$ continuously connects the constants ${{\mathbf{u}}_R}$ and ${{\mathbf{u}}_L}$ (both given) for a fixed t?
Looking at $\frac{{d{\mathbf{w}}}}{{d\xi }} = {\mathbf{r}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))$ which gives the integral curves of the vector field ${\mathbf{r}}$, I integrate

$$\int_{{\mathbf{w}}(\xi  = \lambda ({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ) = {{\mathbf{u}}_R}) = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R}))}^{{\mathbf{w}}(\xi  = \lambda ({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ) = {{\mathbf{u}}_L}) = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L}))} {d{\mathbf{w}}(\xi ) = \int_{\xi  = \lambda ({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ) = {{\mathbf{u}}_R}) = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R})}^{\xi  = \lambda ({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ) = {{\mathbf{u}}_L}) = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L})} {{\mathbf{r}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))} d\xi } $$

which gives

$${\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L})) - {\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R})) = {{\mathbf{u}}_L} - {{\mathbf{u}}_R} = \int_{\xi  = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R})}^{\xi  = \lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L})} {{\mathbf{r}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))d\xi }. $$
Since the integral on the right hand side is a continuous function of ${\mathbf{w}}$  (${\mathbf{r}}$ is continuous), we can write ${{\mathbf{u}}_L} - {{\mathbf{u}}_R} = {\mathbf{f}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))$, so that ${\mathbf{w}}(\xi )$ connects ${{\mathbf{u}}_L}$ and ${{\mathbf{u}}_R}$ continuously.

Is this explanation correct?

(This is from chapter 5.2, p.235 in the book 'Front Tracking for Hyperbolic Conservation Laws' by Risebro, Holden. Link to chapter 5: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4380/v15/beskjeder/chapter5.pdf)

Comment: I'm having trouble working out the meaning of "connects $\mathbf u_L$ and $\mathbf u_R$ continuously."  You start by mentioning "a system of two ODEs" by which I assume is meant $\frac{{d{\mathbf{w}}}}{{d\xi }} = {\mathbf{r}}({\mathbf{w}}(\xi ))$.  But thereafter we are only told $\mathbf r$ is a (continuous) "vector field", so it's hard to know what reasoning we can apply.  I then make out that $\mathbf u_L$ and $\mathbf u_R$ serve (as constant vectors) to supply initial(?) conditions of a kind.  Toward the end of the Question there is a line that subtracts those two conditions, to get...

Comment: ... ${\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_L})) - {\mathbf{w}}(\lambda ({{\mathbf{u}}_R})) = {{\mathbf{u}}_L} - {{\mathbf{u}}_R}$.  That much is certainly not surprising.  But what does "connects... continuously" mean here?

Comment: I think it means that we can draw a continuous curve between the points ${{\mathbf{u}}_R}$ and ${{\mathbf{u}}_L}$ in ${\mathbf{u}} = ({u_1},{u_2})$ - space, but I'm not sure. See figure 5.2 p.239 in the link i posted above where the curves ${R_1}$ and ${R_2}$ connect the point ${\mathbf{L}} = {{\mathbf{u}}_L}$ to any point  ${{\mathbf{u}}_R}$ on ${R_1}$ or ${R_2}$ continuously.

Comment: Perhaps what you are asking about is related to the system of ODEs being [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics))?